# Use custom template name in <xsl:apply-templates>

Tags: xslt

Currently I have this code which calls the "user" template for each user node.

```
<xsl:for-each select="./user|./UnformatedUser">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
    <xsl:with-param name="span"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, I now want to use a template named "fulluser" for all users. I've tried adding `name="fulluser"` to the `<xsl:apply-templates>` tag but it didn't work.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation which XSLT instruction to use for each case. :)

Comment: I don't see how your code " *calls the "user" template for each user node* "...

Comment: Doesn't apply-templates call the template named just like the node?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The [`<xsl:apply-templates>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Applying-Template-Rules) instruction doesn't use a template name to select a template for execution** on a particular node. It only uses the match pattern of templates when deciding which template to select.

**To select for execution a template by name, use the [`<xsl:call-template>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#named-templates) instruction**.

Answer (score 2):

why not use xsl:call-template ?